# Object not found error in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeIgniter and i'm following the tutorial in codeIgniter and try to view the pages like this ("localhost/mysite/index.php/pages/view/about") but i'm getting the following error.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16

Comment: Have you created `pages.php` as a **controller**? And `view()` as a method?

Comment: yes i have crated pages.php and view method

Comment: post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

From your URL

```
localhost/mysite/index.php/pages/view/about
It seems that you have:
Controller: pages
Method: pages
Parameter One: about
```

Make sure that, the controller "Pages:

And

Method "pages" exist.
And also there are files:

```
application/controllers/pages.php
```

and

```
application/views/about.php
```

Comment: what i have is : Controller-Pages,Method-view and my about.php is in application/views/pages/about.php

Comment: I did not get your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter URLs mostly go base_url/controller/method, they don't specify 'view'.

Have you tried:

```
localhost/mysite/index.php/pages/about ?
```

That assumes a controller called 'pages' and a method called 'about'. You should also have a view called 'about.php'.

You can also check that the class names match the filename.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i didn't set the base_url in config.php.i solved the problem by seting the base_url.